# Sparse Matrix Vector Product on Multiple GPUs

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, sparse-matrix, multi-gpu

I was wondering what the fastest way of computing a sparse matrix-vector product y = Ax in CUDA on multiple (let say n) GPUs is.

My naive approach would be to divide the vector x and y into n chunks, 1 chunk on each GPU. Then also split up the matrix A in smaller n^2 blocks A_ij and computing

```
y_i = \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j, // GPU j stores A_{i,j} and x_j, result is copied 
                          // to and summed up on GPU i
```

on the different GPUs j=1..n with let's say cuSPARSE. Would this work? With the unified memory architecture, in principle all GPUs should be able to access the global memory.

Is the memory transfer between the GPUs going to be incredibly slow? I don't expect a large speed up but I was wondering if it is going to be slower than doing the matrix-vector multiplication on 1 single GPU.

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer to this question, it is far to broad. There has been a *lot* of research done on the sparse matrix vector product for distributed memory systems, including GPUs.  You would be better off reading some of that than asking a question like this here on [SO]

Comment: You are right. I guess what I was looking for is a cheap/simple implementation (reusing calls to cuSPARSE) that performs ok-ish on multiple GPUs.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach.  Don't break up the vector `x` into chunks.  Transfer `x` to all GPUs.

Break up the `A` matrix according to rows.  So, for example, if `A` had 9 rows, and you have 3 GPUs, then transfer rows 1-3 of `A` to the first GPU, 4-6 of `A` to the second GPU, and 7-9 of `A` to the third GPU.

Then compute the 3 individual pieces of `y` on the 3 GPUs:

```
y[1-3] = A[1-3]*x
y[4-6] = A[4-6]*x
y[7-9] = A[7-9]*x
```

Each of those 3 operations could be done with [`cusparse<T>csrmv`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrmv), for example (or [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_spmv.html) now has an spmv routine also).

Reassembly of the `y` vector should be trivial (concatenation).
There is no need for inter-GPU data transfer during the computation, only on transfer of results (`y`).

A possible "optimization" would be to partition `A` based on "work" rather than naively by rows.  But the benefit of this would depend on the structure of `A`, so would require analysis.  A simplistic approach to this optimization could be to just break up `A` based on (approximately) equalizing the number of NZ elements in each chunk.

Comment: A graph decomposition to distribute the matrix would be a another standard approach I would have thought.